# Always on MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

Is there a type of MOSFET or method of configuration so that the MOSFET is always on by default but can be switched off by pulling the gate high/low?

Imagine a case where a device is powered on all the time and it needs to be hard reset by an MCU from time to time. Rather than having the MCU pull the gate high all the time, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, for an NMOS, you can pull the gate high with a resistor. Configure the GPIO as open-drain and only pull down when you want to cut power.

Comment: It is usually going to work out better to use a PMOS high side switch, though.

Comment: Is the gate-source leakage of the MOSFET really a concern compared to the current consumption of the thing that is on almost all the time? This sounds misguided.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks, the module that is always on has a consumption of 15 micro amps but I'm finding that it crashes every now and then and I need a way to hard reset it. So I was looking at how I could keep the module on by default without consuming additional current if that makes sense?

Comment: I see. Yeah that's really low. JFET?

Comment: Thanks I'll look into JFET's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do. This only consumes power when VDD_SW is off. When VDD_SW is on, there is no parasitic power draw.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAMXnr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Trying to switch GND instead of VDD has the potential to create a lot of subtle problems that are difficult to explain fully. I strongly recommend that you use PMOS and switch VDD instead of GND. There are exceptions and if you want to post a schematic of your setup maybe one of the exceptions will apply to you.

I assume there are other IO connections to the device you need to de-power. When you set the GPIO high to turn off VDD_SW, you will also need to make sure none of those IO connections are driven high, otherwise the device may not power down properly. In order to power down, devices typically need to have all pins down at GND. If any pin is driven high or pulled high with a resistor, the device may stay powered on.

Technically, MOSFET gates do leak a little bit. But usually it is not a problem, even in micropower circuits powered from coin cells and whatnot. If you ever make a nanopower circuit, I guess you can keep the leakage in the back of your mind. The leakage also increases at higher temperatures.

Comment: Thanks this looks great, I'll test is out on my breadboard and great tip about powering down the other GPIO pins.

Answer (score 1):

1: Yes, it's called a "Depletion MOSFET"

2: just like it doesn't take power for a hook to hold a cup suspended over a benchtop, It doesn't take power to pull a MOSFET gate high all the time, the gate is a capacitor, it only takes electric current to switch from on to off or vice-versa: just use a regular MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks, so I can use a pull up resistor on the MOSFET and not worry about current leakage?

Comment: @P_J The problem is finding a depletion device to actually buy. Also, do you actually have a clear image of what leakage actually is? It sounds like you don't. If you are pulling the gate high and one of the other terminals is low, how can you not have leakage?

Comment: I have never seen or used a depletion mode FET in real life. Is there one that would be suitable for the OP's application?

Comment: The OPs application does nor require a depletion MOSFET, and as they are not very common I do not reccomend one.

Comment: @mkeith JFETs are universally depletion-mode. As are vacuum tubes, not that they're relevant these days. I know that UnitedSiC makes some silicon carbide JFETs rated out to 1200 volts at 10s of amps, which should cover pretty much anything.